# How to include libcds in VS2015 project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libcds

I'm working on windows. How to include the CDS library in VS project? I could not find 'include' directory, nor 'lib' directory.

http://libcds.sourceforge.net/doc/cds-api/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a header only library, just put it in a folder and add a include directory to that folder with visual studio under `Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directory` and then all you have to do is

```
#include <FolderWhereCDSIsAt\allocator.h>
```

or

```
#include <FolderWhereCDSIsAt\cache_line.h>
```